# Need Partial week query in which week comes under one month only if week cross next then it will consider in next month week

Tags: sql, oracle

I have data like this:-

```
01-05-2022 to 07-05-2022
08-05-2022 to 14-05-2022
15-05-2022 to 21-05-2022
22-05-2022 to 28-05-2022
29-05-2022 to 04-06-2022
and so on....
```

I want data would be like:-

```
01-05-2022 to 07-05-2022
08-05-2022 to 14-05-2022
15-05-2022 to 21-05-2022
22-05-2022 to 28-05-2022
29-05-2022 to 31-05-2022
01-06-2022 to 04-06-2022
05-06-2022 to 11-06-2022 
and so on....
```

Week First day should be Sunday.

In this 29-05-2022 to 04-06-2022 is considered as a one week
Means need partial slipt within week in that particular month only.

Would be great for the help.
Thanks in Advance

Comment: You need to generate this setting start and end date I guess?

Comment: Which DBMS you are using ?

Comment: Yes Start and end of the week first day should be sunday and last day  should saturday.

Comment: Oracle SQL  :- if week count crosses month it should count till last month only as mentioned the dates above

Answer (score 0):

You can use a recursive sub-query to generate the rows:

```sql
WITH dates (start_date, in_month_end_date, end_date) AS (
  SELECT start_date,
         LEAST(end_date, LAST_DAY(start_date)),
         end_date
  FROM   table_name
UNION ALL
  SELECT in_month_end_date + 1,
         end_date,
         end_date
  FROM   dates
  WHERE  in_month_end_date < end_date
)
SEARCH DEPTH FIRST BY start_date SET order_id
SELECT start_date,
       in_month_end_date AS end_date
FROM   dates;
```

Which, for the sample data:

```sql
CREATE TABLE table_name (start_date, end_date) AS
SELECT DATE '2022-05-01' + (LEVEL - 1) * 7,
       DATE '2022-05-01' + LEVEL * 7 - 1
FROM   DUAL
CONNECT BY LEVEL <= 6;
```

Outputs:

| START_DATE | END_DATE |
| --- | --- |
| 2022-05-01 00:00:00 | 2022-05-07 00:00:00 |
| 2022-05-08 00:00:00 | 2022-05-14 00:00:00 |
| 2022-05-15 00:00:00 | 2022-05-21 00:00:00 |
| 2022-05-22 00:00:00 | 2022-05-28 00:00:00 |
| 2022-05-29 00:00:00 | 2022-05-31 00:00:00 |
| 2022-06-01 00:00:00 | 2022-06-04 00:00:00 |
| 2022-06-05 00:00:00 | 2022-06-11 00:00:00 |

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/059BuuDk)